# pattern to match complete word in Filebeat multi line pattern

Tags: filebeat

I am using Filebeat multiline pattern in filebeat.yml that is taking its input from a single file as follows:

```html
2016-10-06 14:36:00.419 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : requestStartIdentifier: Identifier
2016-10-06 14:36:00.419 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : requestUri: 
2016-10-06 14:36:00.420 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : HttpServletRequest:
 ContentType: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 ContextPath: 
 LocalAddr: 
 LocalName: 
 PathInfo: 
 PathTranslated: 
 QueryString: 
 RequestURI: 
 RequestURL: 
 RemoteHost: 
 ServletPath: 
 Header: Host: 
 Header: Content-Length: 
 Header: Accept-Encoding: 
 Header: SOAPAction: ""
 Header: User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 
 Header: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 Header: Connection: Keep-Alive
 Header: Accept: text/xml
 
2016-10-06 14:36:00.420 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : uri: , request:
<env:Envelope></env:Envelope>

2016-10-06 14:36:00.419 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : requestStartIdentifier: Identifier
2016-10-06 14:36:00.419 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : requestUri: 
2016-10-06 14:36:00.420 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : HttpServletRequest:
 ContentType: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 ContextPath: 
 LocalAddr: 
 LocalName: 
 PathInfo: 
 PathTranslated: 
 QueryString: 
 RequestURI: 
 RequestURL: 
 RemoteHost: 
 ServletPath: 
 Header: Host: 
 Header: Content-Length: 
 Header: Accept-Encoding: 
 Header: SOAPAction: ""
 Header: User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 
 Header: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 Header: Connection: Keep-Alive
 Header: Accept: text/xml
 
2016-10-06 14:36:00.420 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : uri: , request:
<env:Envelope></env:Envelope>
```

filebeat.yml

```html
multiline:
pattern: Identifier
negate: true
match: after
```

I use the above config to match 'Identifier'  in the line . 
Output should be as desired

```html
event -1 :
2016-10-06 14:36:00.419 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : requestStartIdentifier: Identifier
2016-10-06 14:36:00.419 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : requestUri: 
2016-10-06 14:36:00.420 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : HttpServletRequest:
 ContentType: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 ContextPath: 
 LocalAddr: 
 LocalName: 
 PathInfo: 
 PathTranslated: 
 QueryString: 
 RequestURI: 
 RequestURL: 
 RemoteHost: 
 ServletPath: 
 Header: Host: 
 Header: Content-Length: 
 Header: Accept-Encoding: 
 Header: SOAPAction: ""
 Header: User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 
 Header: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 Header: Connection: Keep-Alive
 Header: Accept: text/xml
 
2016-10-06 14:36:00.420 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : uri: , request:
<env:Envelope></env:Envelope>

event -2 :
2016-10-06 14:36:00.419 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : requestStartIdentifier: Identifier
2016-10-06 14:36:00.419 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : requestUri: 
2016-10-06 14:36:00.420 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : HttpServletRequest:
 ContentType: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 ContextPath: 
 LocalAddr: 
 LocalName: 
 PathInfo: 
 PathTranslated: 
 QueryString: 
 RequestURI: 
 RequestURL: 
 RemoteHost: 
 ServletPath: 
 Header: Host: 
 Header: Content-Length: 
 Header: Accept-Encoding: 
 Header: SOAPAction: ""
 Header: User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 
 Header: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 Header: Connection: Keep-Alive
 Header: Accept: text/xml
 
2016-10-06 14:36:00.420 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : uri: , request:
<env:Envelope></env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample input, it looks like we can use the lines containing `requestStartIdentifier: Identifier` to signal the start of a new event. I used https://play.golang.org/p/BZ2ujeOZZ- to test the different multiline parameters.

Filebeat config:

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    - input_type: log
      paths:
        - input.txt
      multiline:
        pattern: 'requestStartIdentifier: Identifier$'
        negate:  true
        match:   after

output:
  console:
    pretty: true
```

Filebeat output (with newlines expanded):

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2016-10-06T21:51:27.244Z",
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "host",
    "name": "host"
  },
  "input_type": "log",
  "message": "2016-10-06 14:36:00.419 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : requestStartIdentifier: Identifier
2016-10-06 14:36:00.419 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : requestUri: 
2016-10-06 14:36:00.420 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : HttpServletRequest:
    ContentType: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    ContextPath: 
    LocalAddr: 
    LocalName: 
    PathInfo: 
    PathTranslated: 
    QueryString: 
    RequestURI: 
    RequestURL: 
    RemoteHost: 
    ServletPath: 
    Header: Host: 
    Header: Content-Length: 
    Header: Accept-Encoding: 
    Header: SOAPAction: \"\"
    Header: User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 
    Header: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Header: Connection: Keep-Alive
    Header: Accept: text/xml

2016-10-06 14:36:00.420 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : uri: , request:
\u003cenv:Envelope\u003e\u003c/env:Envelope\u003e
",
  "offset": 962,
  "source": "input.txt",
  "type": "log"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2016-10-06T21:51:27.244Z",
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "host",
    "name": "host"
  },
  "input_type": "log",
  "message": "2016-10-06 14:36:00.419 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : requestStartIdentifier: Identifier
2016-10-06 14:36:00.419 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : requestUri: 
2016-10-06 14:36:00.420 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : HttpServletRequest:
    ContentType: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    ContextPath: 
    LocalAddr: 
    LocalName: 
    PathInfo: 
    PathTranslated: 
    QueryString: 
    RequestURI: 
    RequestURL: 
    RemoteHost: 
    ServletPath: 
    Header: Host: 
    Header: Content-Length: 
    Header: Accept-Encoding: 
    Header: SOAPAction: \"\"
    Header: User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 
    Header: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Header: Connection: Keep-Alive
    Header: Accept: text/xml

2016-10-06 14:36:00.420 DEBUG 29695 --- [XNIO-2 task-2] c.a.a.s.endpoint.endone.server  : uri: , request:
\u003cenv:Envelope\u003e\u003c/env:Envelope\u003e",
  "offset": 1923,
  "source": "input.txt",
  "type": "log"
}
```

Comment: hi AJ.. that didn't work . my log file is not seperated into events depending on '\$\$\$' pattern... can you please suggest me to do with the word.. 'requestStartIdentifier'

Comment: Could you provide a larger sample log with multiple lines. And please indicate what the expected result is (show what belongs in each event). I don't understand what your logs look like.

Comment: Thanks for the new info. My response has been updated.

Comment: @lakshmi Did the updated answer address your problem/question? If so could you mark it as the solution. If not, what problem are you having with the patterns.